# How to pass a value from gridview to another page through session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to pass a single value from grid view to another page with the help of session when pressing a button. How can achieve it?

c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindEmployeeDetails();
    }
}

protected void BindEmployeeDetails()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select uniqueref,fldCustomerName,fldCustomerAddress,fldCustomerCity,fldOrderValue,fldINRrEUR from asm", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
        GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
    }
}

protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("add.aspx");
}

protected void Edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("edit.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Some code examples would be great..

Comment: @SonerGönül In each row the first column is the primary key column, when i press the edit button it will redirect to another page that is edit page. where i edit the corresponding column with the help of the primary key which is present in the session variable in that edit page.

Comment: @ramits, you need so show that you have made a start and the question is answerable. **Please show some of your code**.

Answer (score 1):

Set value into `Session`, like this:

```
// We will say that `GridView1.PrimaryKey` is an int 
Session["YourGridValue"] = GridView1.Value;
```

Read value from `Session`, like this:

```
   // Check first to make sure our value is in Session
   if(null != Session["YourGridValue"])
   {
        int sessionValue = (int)Session["YourGridValue"];
   }
```

Note: The value in `Session` is stored as an `Object`, but can be a string, int, List, etc.; so you must cast it to the correct type when retrieving the value.

Comment: In my grid view the first column is the primary key column. I have an edit button on each row of the grid view. If I press the edit button it will redirect to another page that is the edit page. And now my question is while redirecting to edit page I want to transfer the primary key of the corresponding column to an session variable and with the help of that session variable edit the particular grid view column in another page. How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is the logic to redirect to the edit page, in a GridView command event called `Edit` or is the field a link to the edit page?

Comment: @Karl Anderson Yes sir i have an edit button on each row and i want to edit the corresponding row in another page with the help of the primary key that is present in the session variable of that edit page.

Comment: @ramits - It would help significantly if you posted your markup for your GridView and any code-behind you have that interacts with the GridView.

Comment: @Karl Anderson sir i just want to transfer the primary key value of the selected column to another page with the help of session. when pressing the button.

Comment: @ramits - okay, I get that, but why are you so adamant about not showing your code? I don't know if you understand what StackOverflow is, but we deal with coding issues here, not taking requirements and building code for people. Show us your code!

Comment: @Karl Anderson sir i posted the code above.